# Merging Ask Ubuntu and Unix Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, community

I've forced myself to participate on the Unix Stack Exchange, moderating, answering, providing essential comments and so on.

I'd like to do the above tasks on Ask Ubuntu, even though my favorite OS is Debian.

Why have Ask Ubuntu and Unix Stack Exchange not been merged? Is it because of a policy or for historical reasons? I predict if they are merged, the number of contributions will be increased…

Comment: Ubuntu is wandering off in its own strange direction, and may no longer resemble traditional Linux.

Comment: @Mark for certain definitions of "traditional Linux", "strange direction".

Comment: A number of users spent quality time on both sites. If you can't, you should focus on one site.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [Fork it!](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/fork-it/):

> So, Ubuntu, Linux, I get it, it’s clearly not the same thing. If you love Ubuntu, we have a site for you. If you love Linux and Unix, we have a site for you. A Stack Exchange can’t work without a community that loves a subject, and love is very… specific. Fighting human nature is hard: the factionalism and fork-happiness of the Unix world has been a hallmark of that community ever since BSD vs. System V, and Stack Exchange can no more bridge that gap than we can unite the Judean resistance.

Comment: Of course i'm sorry for Cannonical Company, They have all of GNU\Linux feature but think they have been seperated from world...!

Comment: Considering that Ask Ubuntu has the [third highest amount of traffic in the Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic), I'd say we have a fairly large userbase :)